# Problem displaying even numbers and odd numbers in an array list

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

For this program, I would like display the even numbers and its sum when the "even sum" button is clicked  and the same thing for the odd numbers when the "odd sum" is clicked. I have been able to successfully get the sum of both even and odd numbers but I cannot display the even and odd numbers separately. I'm working with IntelliJ idea and a gui.

My code for even sum button:

```
 BtnSumE.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int sumE = 0;
            for (int counter = 0; counter < aryNums.size(); counter++) {
                if (aryNums.get(counter) % 2 == 0) {
                    sumE += aryNums.get(counter);
                    TxtArea.setText(String.valueOf(aryNums.get(counter)));
                    TxtArea2.setText("The sum of the even integers is " + valueOf(sumE));
                }
```

My code for odd sum button:

```
BtnSumO.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int sumO = 0;
            for (int counter = 0; counter < aryNums.size(); counter++) {
                if (aryNums.get(counter) % 2!= 0) {
                    sumO += aryNums.get(counter);
                    TxtArea.setText(String.valueOf(aryNums.get(counter)));
                    TxtArea2.setText("The sum of the odd integers is " + valueOf(sumO));
                }
```

When I run the program for even sum I get "74" and for odd sum I get "263"...

My array list (aryNums) has these numbers [0, 2, 23, 74, 263]

I have tried to do
`TxtArea.setText(String.valueOf(counter));`
for both and when I run it, for even sum I get "3" and for odd sum I get "4"

Any help would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it is changing the sum in the text area in every iteration of the loop and I think you shouldn't do that. You need to finish the loop before declaring the sum.

```
int sumO = 0;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < aryNums.size(); counter++) {
          if (aryNums.get(counter) % 2!= 0) {
                 sumO += aryNums.get(counter);       
          }
     }
     TxtArea.setText(String.valueOf(aryNums.get(counter)));
     TxtArea2.setText("The sum of the odd integers is " + String.valueOf(sumO)); // you erased the String
```

Same goes with the even.